# what its the code to make the cursor have asterisk that follows it of the 90 theme of this page

Tags: css

how do i add below feature to my css?
its not for this page of course, but i couldn't find the code about this with the firefox inspector. and also and this be done with other letter and images? and this only uses css3 right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is done using JavaScript instead of CSS.

You can see its code by viewing the page source, then search for "Fairy Dust Cursor".

The exact code can be found in [Tim Holman's Github profile](https://github.com/tholman/cursor-effects).